# PhantomJS Issue writing to file fs. Can't find variable: fs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying out phantomJS for the first time and i have successfully extracted som data from a site, but when i try to write some content to a file i get the error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fs

Here is my script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    var fs = require('fs');

    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };

    page.open("http://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=motorbike", function(status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js", function() {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    var imgs = {
                        title: [],
                        href: [],
                        ext: [],
                        src: [],
                        alt: []
                    };
                    $('a.pinImageWrapper').each(function() {
                        imgs.title.push($(this).attr('title'));
                        imgs.href.push($(this).attr('href'));
                        var ext = $(this).children('.pinDomain').html();
                        imgs.ext.push(ext);
                        var img = $(this).children('.fadeContainer').children('img.pinImg');
                        imgs.src.push(img.attr('src'));
                        imgs.alt.push(img.attr('alt'));
                    });
                    if (imgs.title.length >= 1) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.title.length; i++) {
                            console.log(imgs.title[i]);
                            console.log(imgs.href[i]);
                            console.log(imgs.ext[i]);
                            console.log(imgs.src[i]);
                            console.log(imgs.alt[i]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('No pins found');
                    }
                    fs.write('foo.txt', 'bar');
                });
                phantom.exit();
            });
        }
    });
```

What am i missing out here?

**Edit:** Of the response on this question i learned why i couldnt reach the data inside the evalute, and how i could access it.

```
            var page = require('webpage').create();
        var fs = require('fs');

        page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };

        openPinPage('motorbike');

        function openPinPage(keyword) {
            page.open("http://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=" + keyword, function(status) {
                if (status === "success") {
                    page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js", function() {
                        getImgsData();
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function getImgsData() {
            var data = page.evaluate(function() {
                var imgs = {
                    title: [],
                    href: [],
                    ext: [],
                    src: [],
                    alt: []
                };
                $('a.pinImageWrapper').each(function() {
                    imgs.title.push($(this).attr('title'));
                    imgs.href.push($(this).attr('href'));
                    var ext = $(this).children('.pinDomain').html();
                    imgs.ext.push(ext);
                    var img = $(this).children('.fadeContainer').children('img.pinImg');
                    imgs.src.push(img.attr('src'));
                    imgs.alt.push(img.attr('alt'));
                });
                return imgs;
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < data.title.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.title[i]);
            };
            phantom.exit();
        }
```

Comment: I've added an answer to show how can you write some webpage content to file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have `phantomjs` objects in `page.evaluate` because that is a webpage. I'll give you a simple example how can you achieve what you are doing.

If you want to write some content of `webpage` in a file you have to return those contens from `page.evaluate`. and you will get those values in `page.open`. Here you have access to `fs`, so you can write those contents.

I'm showing with a simple example how you can you write some `webpage` title to a file.

```
page.open("http://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=motorbike", function(status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js", function() {

                var title = page.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.title;  // here I don't have access to fs I'll return title of document from here.
                });
                console.log(title) //I got the title now I can write here.
                fs.write('foo.txt', title);
                phantom.exit();
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Straight from [the docs for `page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> Evaluates the given function in the context of the web page. The
>   execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom
>   object and it can't probe its own setting.

No further explanation needed.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Tomalak's answer:

Your `evaluate()`ed function isn't run in the context of your Phantoms script, but in the page, so it can't see `fs`.

In this, case, you'll want your function to read the results of your script in some other way.